# close form when application loses focus

Tags: vb.net

My form is displayed as TopMost on my application. The problem I have is that whenever I minimize my application or it loses focus, the form remains displaying. I want to be able to minimize my application  or move to another and also hide or close my form. Once the application regains the focus, then unhide or open the form again.

Here is what I worked out on the form's closing event:

```
Private Sub frmNavigation_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Static Minimize As Boolean

    If Minimize = True Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Me.Hide()
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried using the same code in the applications `WindowDeactivate` event but nothing happens.

Comment: In your code Minimize will have the default False value and it will never be set to True, so nothing happens. Perhaps you have more code that you haven't shown for this? But, I am confused by your description and think you could make it clearer.

Comment: The main idea with the TopMost thing is precisely that, to stay on top of everything regardless focus. Is that what you really want or can you try without TopMost?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I was trying to accomplish was if my application loses focus, then also minimize my form. My code above does not really work, so I have to ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not show how you create the instance of your `frmNavigation`. I am assuming that you are using the Show Method, so just use the version of [Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx) that you pass in the top level window. That will assign the owner of the form, it will then stay on top of your Main Form and minimize and restore with it also. If this doesn't work please show how you are creating and showing your form.

```
frmNavigation.Show(Me)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer to the question. MSDN had an article on this very issue.

it can be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186908#appliesto